# Visual Studio no folders or files included in .Net Core projects, and can't manually include them

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

This is happening with all new .Net Core projects (Console App, Class Library, Web Application etc), no matter the directory or drive I put them in.

The project is created and loads, but only the absolute bare minimum skeleton-of-a-skeleton is shown.

Quick screenshot:

[image: No files included]

If I tell it to show hidden files, I can see the whole project has been made:

[image: hidden files]

Now if I select any file or folder, right click and choose 'Include in Project', nothing happens! I've tried closing and reopening Visual Studio, and have tried restarting my laptop, but still nothing happens.

Other projects work fine, e.g. WPF, Xamarin or anything that isn't done via .Net Core.

Is there a setting I may have missed or need to change somewhere? It's a strange issue indeed.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have .net core installed? https://www.microsoft.com/net/download

Comment: @Thili - Yeah, and just tried reinstalling it too. Might have to try reinstalling VS2017.

Comment: Maybe you need to update visual studio. Currently version 15.8.7 is the latest version. Go to Help -> Check for updates.

Comment: Please share the .csrpoj file. does it happen on any new projects?

Comment: Yeah, update first, then reinstall sounds right. Wow :) Could also try with no extensions enabled to see if one of those may be causing trouble.

Comment: I recall you can call "devenv.exe /setup" to reconfigure VS. Haven't had to use that in a long time, so it may not even be useful anymore. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/setup-devenv-exe?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out reinstalling Visual Studio was the only answer.

As in, full uninstall, delete the leftover folders in the old install location, then reinstall from scratch.

If I tried the update option, it failed at the start of the download. My guess is something messed up in Vistual Studio. It was fine before. The only thing I changed was that I recently installed AVG Antivirus, which seems way too strict on what processes it allows and disallows. AVG is now uninstalled.